# R: Make dataframes in a function with name dependent on input

Tags: r, function, namespaces

So I have created a dataframe of the results of a few footballteams for the years 1950-2020, including the winrate.

I now want to compute the winrate of each of those teams per year. So I will have 70 winrates per team.

To do this, I have written a function that computes the winrates of each team in a given year:

```
winrate_py_f <- function(team, data, year1){
  years = filter(results, year == year1)
  won = filter(years, home_team == team & difference > 0 | away_team == team & difference < 0)
  matches = filter(years, home_team == team | away_team == team)
  winrate{_year1} = ((nrow(won) / nrow(matches)) * 100)
  return(formatC(winrate))
}
```

Now I want to name the results like this : winrate_1967 for instance for the year 1967. That is what the {_year} part is for, but this doesn't work obviously.

What is the correct way to do this?

To be extra clear:

I would like to call this function with for example (Brazil, data, 1950:2020) so that I would get the winrates of Brazil for every year between 1950 and 2020.

Comment: If you call the function on a range of values, chang ethe `==` to `%in%`.  What is `results` object.  It is not passed in as argument

Comment: Please include all packages you use

Comment: Aha okay thank you! Results is a dataframe with footballmatches, with data about the year, the scores etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the assignment within the function, return the output and then `assign` the values of the function to an object created with `paste`

```
winrate_py_f <- function(data, team year1){
    years = filter(data, year == year1)
    won = filter(years, home_team == {{team}} & difference > 0 | 
              away_team == {{team}} & difference < 0)
    matches = filter(years, home_team == {{team}} | away_team == {{team}})
     ((nrow(won) / nrow(matches)) * 100)
    
  }
```

call the function as

```
assign(paste0("winrate_", 1967), winrate_py_f(data, Brazil, 1967))
```

Now check for

```
winrate_1967
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the 'year1' as a single value and not a range of values